# Returning strictly lesser element using upper_bound

Tags: c++

I want to find the greatest element in an array which is less than K. I am trying to use the `upper_bound()` function:

```
upper_bound(a,a+n,k, std::greater<int>());
```

For `int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` and `int k = 3;`, I want the output to be `1`, because `a[1] = 2`, which is the greatest element less than `k`.

However, the above comparator gives the output as `4`. How can I write my own comparator for this?

Comment: If your collection is not ordered, [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) is not the correct function to use.  `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is not ordered to have *greater* values first.

Comment: I can use std::lower_bound and then decrement the pointer once to get the required index, but I wanted to know if it could be done using upper_bound().

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of

```
std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), v, std::less<>{})
```

with `std::upper_bound` is:

```
std::upper_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), v, std::greater<>{}).base();
```

where all things are reversed (looking from the *end*, opposite order).

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/mxSTFi)